# How to prove that these level curves intersect

Tags: mathematical-economics, proof

I have two functions:

$$F(x,y) = U_1'(c_1)(a_1-b_1)+U_2'(c_2) = 0$$
$$G(x,y) = U_1'(c_1)+U_2'(c_2)(a_2-b_2) = 0$$

where $c_i=a_i(x-y)+yb_i, i=1,2.$ the utility functions $U_1,U_2$ are twice differentiable, increasing and concave functions, and $a-d$ are constants.

Computation shows that a solution exists where $0<y<1/2<x, x+y<1,F(x,y)=G(x,y)=0$, i.e., the functions intersect at the $x,y$ state plane:

[image: image of the x,y state plane]

How to prove analytically that the functions intersect in the area $0<y<1/2<x, x+y<1?$ If we know the following:
$$0.5\leq x\leq1; 0\leq y\leq0.5,$$

$$  y\leq x $$
$$F(1,0)>0,F(1/2,1/2)<0$$
$$G(1,0)>0,G(1/2,0)>0,G(1/2,1/2)<0,$$
$$G(1/2,\dot{y})=0,F(1/2,\dot{y})<0$$

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you denote by $\dot{y}$?

Comment: Hi! its the value of $y$ that satisfies $G(1/2,y)=0$.  By $G(1/2,0)>0,G(1/2,1/2)<0$, we know that a solution exists where $G(1/2,y)=0,  0<y<1/2.$  I denote that value by $\dot{y}$. We also know by other assumptions that at the point $G(1/2, \dot{y})=0$, F is negative: $F(1/2,\dot{y})<0. $ Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Now I realised my axes legends are wrong in the figure. y-axis is for y and x-axis for x! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi vonenzo! I dont' understand what does it mean $U'_i(x,y)$, that is the superscript, I know it could be the sign of a first derivative, but $U_i$ are  functions of two variables, so there should be partial derivatives, so: what are  the $U'_i$?

Comment: Hi! It is the total derivative of $U$, so indeed it is the first derivative. Basically, consumption $c_i$ depends on two variables $x,y$. The utility functions $U_i(c_i)$ are here differentiated with respect to $c_i$, and now written explicitly for variables  $x,y$.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: So it is $U_i(c_i(x,y))$ and $U'_i$ is the derivative with respect to $c_i$? I think you should write it explicitely, otherwise the two equations make no sense.

Comment: Do you mean, instead that $U'_i$ is the total differential of $U_i(x,y)$? This also should be clarified, as  the notation $U'$ for the differential is not standard, and, morover,  a differential is not a first derivative, as you seem to suggest. You should clarify better the formulas, I think, in order to  allow other contributors to answer.

Comment: I use *total differential* , *differential*,  *total derivative* as synonimous, *differential* is for me the most usual term.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I clarified the formulas now. Hopefully it makes more sense.